# Routing through subdirectory based on attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building blog which uses an Article model to support two distinct article types with their own index pages.  I'm trying to set it up the way Hubspot has their blog using a single model for admin purposes (the only difference between the types is the intended audience so it's a dropdown in the form).

I want the url aliasing to either route to `/foo/:article_id` or `/bar/:article_id` depending on the value of the `@article.type` attribute.

Is this achievable using the rails routes and a single model/controller?

I have tried:

```
resources :articles, :path => "foo"
resources :articles, :path => "bar"
```

which works, but:

1. I'm stuck checking the url and `article.type` in the show action to determine whether it's a `foo` or `bar` which doesn't seem ideal.
2. I do not want to be able to post a foo article and be able to view it by going to `/bar/:foo_article_id` which can be done here.
3. It uses a single index action meaning the view formatting will have a bunch of conditionals based on the type which feels hacky.

Are there any other solutions that don't have these downsides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what you're referring to is something called [`Single Table Inheritance`](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/):

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  # needs a "type" column
end

#app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < Article
end

#app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < Article
end
```

Both will use the *articles* table (a reference for any Google searchers!).

---

There are several fixes for this.

The main question you have is that of *controllers*.

You're stuck trying to determine which controller structure to use. If you use the above setup (*you* won't have to change anything in your models), you'll be able to differentiate between the two models explicitly. The only thing which remains is to determine which route to use.

To be succinct, I'd use my own module to find the `Article` or `Post`, and send the requests to a *single* controller:

```
#config/routes.rb
%w(foo bar).each do |o|
   get "/#{o}/:id", to: Dispatcher.new(self), as: o.to_sym #-> url.com/foo/1 & url.com/bar/2
end

#lib/dispatcher.rb
class Dispatcher

  #http://blog.arkency.com/2014/01/short-urls-for-every-route-in-your-rails-app/
  ##########################################

  #Init
  def initialize(router)
    @router = router
  end

  #Env
  def call(env)
    id     = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"][:id]
    model  = env["action_dispatch.request.path"].gsub("/", "") #-> /foo
    record = model.titleize.constantize.find id #-> looks up in the specific model (foo/bar)

    if record
      ArticlesController.action("show").call(env)
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end

end
```

Finally, you'll be able to pass the following to the `articles#show` action:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      model = request.path.gsub("/", "") #-> "foo"
      @article = model.titleize.constantize.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm getting an `uninitialized constant Dispatcher` despite the file you referenced being in the `lib` folder.  Does it need to be located elsewhere to be loaded along with the project?

Comment: You might have to add this to `config/application.rb` - `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]` :)

Answer (score 0):

Have three ActiveRecord models instead of one:
`Article`, `FooArticle` and `BarArticle`

The `Article` Model should contain all the attributes and code that's common to both, and it should not have any controller or views

the `FooArticle` model and the `BarArticle` model should both reference `Article` in a `has_one` relationship and use the `delegate` keyword to map the functionality of `Article` up to the more specific versions. Then you can have separate controllers and views for Foo and Bar, but have all the functionality and code in one model.

It would be possible to have a Foo and a Bar both referencing the same Article, so you may have to watch out for that.